# Copying text from an element in jquery and inseting into another elelement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a simple js script that will copy text from a specified div element and paste it into the 'value' field of a form. This is the best I have managed to come up with:

```
var txt=$('div').clone();
$('#name').val(txt);
```

Can somebody please let me know where I am going wrong?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Just a note that 'clone()' will copy the entire DOM element (div in this case) including the HTML markup and any bound events.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var txt=$('div .someclassname').text();

or var txt=$('div #someidname').text();
$('#name').val(txt);
```

it like that.